# Is quickblox api is available free for iOS application for adding feature of video calling

Tags: ios, quickblox

I want to add feature of video calling in my iOS application.I have created one demo using quickblox. I want confirm that can I upload the application on app store without any charges.
Are there any limitation on use of quickblox ? Is the API completely free for iOS?

Comment: [This](http://quickblox.com/plans/) should answer your question, no?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about product pricing. Such questions will be answered by the producer, or should really be addressed to them. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to QuickBlox plans http://quickblox.com/plans/ there are no any limits for number of  VideoChat minutes. It's only 100 Concurent Video Calls per account. QuickBlox won't require payment for Basic plan.

If you need better performance  - you can switch to other plans.

So, answer is Yes - you can upload it without any doubts.

Comment: Thanks Igor Khomenko for your answer.